# If all elements of Lie algebra are nilpotent , is the Lie algebra nilpotent?

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{F}$. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is
nilpotent if and only if, for all $x \in \mathfrak{g}$, $\mathrm{ad}~ x$ is a nilpotent  linear operator on $\mathfrak{g}$.

This is Engel's theorem

My doubt is this:

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra consisting of nilpotent  operators on a finite vector space $V$. Can we say that   $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra consisting of nilpotent  operators on a finite vector space $V$. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Since $x$ nilpotent implies that $\operatorname{ad}(x)$ is nilpotent, we have that $\operatorname{ad}(x)$ is nilpotent for all $x\in \mathfrak{g}$.
By Engel's Theorem $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent.